# I want to send email order confirmation only for status payment complete with Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, status, confirmation

I use Magento 2 for my store and an email order confirmation is send automatically after an order even when the status payment is cancelled, invalid, review...
I want to send an email confirmation only when a payment is completed or processing.

Could you please help me to change the parameter / the configuration to achieve this goal.

Thanks a lot

Majda

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create observer on sales_order_place_after
i will give you an just example
create new file events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="name of observer"
                  instance="Test\Email\Observer\SendEmail" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then create Observer folder in your module

```
<?php

namespace Sivantos\HidePrice\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

    class SendEmail implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
    {

     public function execute(Observer $observer)
        {
         //code 
        }
    }
```